# hide the console window when use batch file to launch a java program?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I use a batch to launch my java application like this

```
start /min java -splash:resources\images\splash\splash.gif com.myproj.MyProjApp
exit
```

There is still a icon on the taskbar. what I want is hide the console window and only add ONE icon which is my application on the taskbar when I click that batch file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
javaw -splash:resources\images\splash\splash.gif com.myproj.MyProjApp
```

instead of what you have there.

Comment: +1
The javaw command is identical to java, except that javaw has no associated console window.